# Triangulations of 3-manifolds in Regina and SnapPy

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, computational-topology

I have been doing some statistical studies on small 3-manifolds, and I note that one can produce larg-ish censuses of triangulations in Regina. Now, the Regina documentation tells us how to convert a single triangulation into SnapPy format, but is mum on any batch way of doing this. Any help appreciated...

Comment: I imagine one can do a lot of things using Regina's Python interface - did you try asking on https://github.com/regina-normal/regina ?

Comment: Thanks, @DimaPasechnik! I did not know it HAD a python interface (it is not super well-documented).

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Actually, the python interface is kind of terrible and seems to violate all known (and some unknown) python design standards. sigh.

Comment: well, I gave up on trying to use any boost-dependent C++ projects. Aren’t there other tools available that can replace Regina here?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Good question. The morally pure thing to do is to read the paper (which exists) and to implement the thing myself. but this is obviously slightly less time efficient.

Comment: I'm one of the authors of Regina, and I got involved in the project largely because of how **good** the documentation was.  Perhaps standards have changed.  The documentation has become more difficult to read since Regina 5.0 -- Doxygen doesn't seem to parse templated code very well. That said, yes I believe there is a way back from SnapPea to Regina triangulations, and I used to use it all the time.

Comment: @IgorRivin - The python interface is very much an late immigrant to regina.  Direct all pleas directly to Ben Burton -- perhaps if enough of us beg, he will grant the python interface permanent residency.

Comment: Finally - you should definitely embrace using iso_sigs.  Much easier than carrying around snappea triangulation files.

Comment: The Python interface is lovely. The main down-side to it, is not all the Regina code has a Python interface.  Ben does most of the Python interface creation and maintenance.

Comment: @RyanBudney As Sam Nead says, the python interface is not "first class".  The proper way to integrate with python is via a package, so you can do  `import regina` or whatever from your jupyter notebook or python program - as far as I know (which, granted, is not very far) you cannot do this. Aside from this, the python interface is for python 2.7, which is about 10 years out of date at this point.

Comment: @SamNead I don't much care what format they come in, as long as I can feed them to SnapPy and get some information out. My reason for this is just extending the work in https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.09532 to bigger manifolds. If you could suggest a workflow that accomplishes that, that would be great!

Comment: @IgorRivin, perhaps.  I don't use the Python interface much at all.  I think what's happened here is that between the core C++ code, the Python interface, and the GUI in all its flavours for various platforms, Regina has likely become a bit too big for the developers.  I pretty much just stick to the C++ code. Back when Ben and I discussed development more actively I noticed how much time Ben was spending on the GUI and suggested we drop that feature.   It's a cute feature to have, but just the C++ and Python interfaces would be plenty of code to manage.

Comment: @RyanBudney I am prejudiced, perhaps, but, especially in the python world, the GUIs are not so hard to develop (and for troglodytes like myself, pretty much superfluous), so I would second your suggestion.

Comment: As a comment, I have noticed there has been activity towards making Regina's Python code Python 3.* compatible. I'm not certain when that release will but I imagine in not too long.

Answer (score 3):

So I have done some of the hand-holding of getting regina and snappy to talk to each other. (Actually, I did this a few years ago, they are better integrated now thanks to the hard work of both development teams, especially with regards to moving isosigs back and forth.)

More specifically, I looked at all ideal (which for regina means at least one ideal vertex) orientable triangulations with 6 or fewer tetrahedra.

Then I threw out the triangulations with finite vertices and the triangulations of solid tori.

The complete data summary is available in Tables 1,2, and 3 at the end of

*Garoufalidis, Stavros; Hodgson, Craig D.; Hoffman, Neil R.; Rubinstein, J. Hyam*, [**The 3D-index and normal surfaces**](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1498032034), Ill. J. Math. 60, No. 1, 289-352 (2016). [ZBL1378.57030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1378.57030).

But the interesting data is also here:

http://math.okstate.edu/people/nhoffman/smalltriangulations.html

I tried to classify things as best as I could with the contemporary tools. However, toroidal mean that it contained an essential embedded tori or Klein bottle, but it could be SFS with over the S^2 with 4 exceptional fibers.

Unfortunately, Regina went through a major update since I implemented the code so it might take a little work to get it running again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Regina has such a feature.  Unfortunately the documentation has become a bit more difficult to read since Regina 5.0. The software we use to generate the documentation (Doxygen) doesn't deal well with highly-templated code, it seems.

You can also import from Orb (perhaps this isn't maintained anymore?) and Matveev's Recogniser.

[Here is the link](https://regina-normal.github.io/engine-docs/classregina_1_1Triangulation_3_013_01_4.html) in the Regina 5.0 API docs for what you want.  The command is in the Triangulation<3> class, and its called **fromSnapPea()**.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try to check it out!

Answer (score 3):

In recent enough versions of SnapPy and Regina, you can just cast a triangulation from one format to the other:

```
from regina import Triangulation3
from snappy import Manifold

M = Manifold("m004") # SnapPy census manifold
T = Triangulation3(M) # to regina

T = Triangulation3("cPcbbbiht") # from iso sig
M = Manifold(T) # to SnapPy
```